# Compare dictionary keys (datetime) with list of tuples[1] and if matches return tuple[0]

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime

I am a beginner(ish) with Python and having trouble with getting the correct syntax for this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have a dictionary and a list of tuples. I would like to compare the key of my dictionary to a value in the tuple, and if meets criteria return a different tuple value. Here's the illustration:

```
dictionary = {datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 12, 9, 30): 30, datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 12, 11, 0): 60, datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 12, 13, 0): 30}

tuplelist = [(1, datetime.time(6, 45, 21)), (2, datetime.time(7, 15, 21)), (3, datetime.time(7, 45, 21)...etc)
```

The goal is to see which increment of 30 minutes my dictionary key falls into, and update it with the increment number stored in tuple list. What I tried:

```
for k,y in dictionary: 
  for i, t in tuplelist:
    if t <= k <= (t+ datetime.timedelta(minutes = 30)):
      dictionary[k] = t
```

The error I got is unable to unpack non iterable type datetime.

Any help and/or explanation is welcome! I am really enjoying learning to code but not from a CS background so always looking for the how it works in addition to just the correct syntax.

Thank you!

Update for working solution:

```
newdic = {}

for k,v in dictionary.items():
  for item in mylist:
    i, t = item
    if t <= k.time() <= (datetime.combine(datetime.today(),t) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)).time():
      newdic.update({i : v})
    else:
      continue
```

Comment: That is not (quite) how you loop over dictionary and list contents.

Comment: The first loop should be `for k, y in dictionary.items():`

Comment: You never use `y`, so you could just use `for k in dictionary:`

Comment: not sure you want to go down pandas route but [pandas.between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) might be useful

Comment: @Barmar I made that update. The code is now: for k in dictionary.items(): for i, t in mylist: if t<= k <= (t+datetime.timedelta(minutes = 30)): dictionary[k] = t.
that is still producing an unable to unpack int type error. I'm suspecting I've written the second loop of my list of tuples incorrectly but can't diagnose exactly.

Comment: @julian I actually have a df elsewhere in the application so already have pandas imported and some functionality built out. I will look into the between time! Appreciate it

Comment: @jmaneaglefan008 It's either `for k, y in dictionary.items():` or `for k in dictionary:`. You seem to have mixed them up with `for k in dictionary.items():`. Don't just copy blindly, think about what it's doing.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, Got it working. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the complete answer. See if it helps resolve early issues up to the comment.

```
import datetime

dictionary = {datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 12, 9, 30): 30,
              datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 12, 11, 0): 60,
              datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 12, 13, 0): 30}

tuplelist = [(1, datetime.time(6, 45, 21)), (2, datetime.time(7, 15, 21)),
             (3, datetime.time(7, 45, 21),)]
for k, y in dictionary.items():
    for item in tuplelist: # get each tuple from the list
        i, t = item # unpack the tuple into i and t
        print(f'{i=} {t=}') # Check i and t values
        # if t <= k <= (t + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)):
        #     dictionary[k] = t
```

Comment: Thank you. This connected the dots for me. I updated my original question with the working solution in case it helps anyone in the future!